# Weird vertical spacing when using `semantic` with `setspace`

Tags: spacing, setspace

I'm writing my dissertation, which needs to be double spaced. There seems to be some issue with semantic inference rules in the presence of `\doublespacing`. When the rule has only one antecedent, the spacing is fine. But with more than one antecedent, the space above the rule shrinks. With single spacing, I do not see this issue.

Am I doing something wrong? If not, is there a workaround? I tried typesetting the rules within the `singlespace` environment, but that did not help.

Here's my MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} %maths
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[nodisplayskipstretch]{setspace}
\usepackage[inference]{semantic}
\doublespacing

\noindent
Blah blah blahhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh
\begin{equation*}
\inference{h1}{c}
\end{equation*}
Blah blah blahhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh
\begin{equation*}
\inference{h1\\h2\\h3\\h4}{c}
\end{equation*}
Blah blah blahhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh
```

Produces:

[image: LaTeX output]